# Непонятная ситуация с подстановкой значения

Tags: jquery, input, javascript, select

Есть такой пример:

```
alert($('#MySelect :selected').text()); //Выводит выбраный текст - всё работает!
$('#MyInput').val("blalbla"); //Выводит значение в input - то же всё работает!
```

Но если делаем так:

```
$('#MyInput').val($('#MySelect :selected').text()); ////Значение в input не попадает, пример не работает
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема (сломал мозг...)?

**Обновление**

Вот у меня примерно вот что: http://jsfiddle.net/13sq5w9q/3/
И у меня на компе не работает. По отдельности - работает.
Использую https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл, в чём проблема. Если `<option>Блабла</option>` - то всё хорошо, инпут всё видит. А вот если:

```
<option>

      Блабла

</option>
```

то в инпуте значение не видится. :) В общем, текст между `<options>` берется целиком и запихивается в `<input>`.

Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/13sq5w9q/4/

Всем огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Тогда можно использовать trim:

> $('.inp1').val($('.sel1 :selected').text())

> $('.inp1').val($('.sel1 :selected').text().trim())

Answer (score 1):

[@MrM](/users/25006/mrm), добавьте пример на jsFiddle, когда это не работает.
Я собрал абстрактный пример: http://jsfiddle.net/dpp5xk4g/1/
Там ваш код работает.

Comment: Да чтож такое... действительно работает.
:option - не влияет.
Сейчас буду разбираться...

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, вам нужно при смене значения селекта менять значение в инпуте, тогда вы забыли написать `:option`.

```
$('#MySelect option:selected').text()
```

Пример http://jsfiddle.net/dpp5xk4g/2/

Comment: @xfloooo, указание селектора option не является обязательным.